Existence of matrix implies rank of matrix
Let $A$ be a $(m \times n)$-matrix with real components. I want to prove that if there exists a $(n \times m)$-matrix $C$ such that $AC = I_m$ with $I_m$ the $(m \times m)$ identity matrix, then it follows that $\mathrm{rank}(A)=m$.
In other proofs I found here, either the opposite was shown or something about the rank of $C$. Any hints would be appreciated.

The following chain of inequalities should suffice :-
$m = rank ({I}_m) = rank (AC) \le \min{\{rank (A), rank (C)\}} \le rank(A) \le \min{\{m,n\}} \le m$,
where $rank (AC) \le \min{\{rank (A), rank (C)\}}$ follows from $col(AB) \subseteq col(A)$ and $row(AB) \subseteq row(B)$.

One question: I think for this it would also be enough to have proven $\mathrm{rank}(AC) \leq \mathrm{rank}(A)$ right? Which follows from $\mathrm{col}(AC) \subset \mathrm{col}(A)$.

Sure. That works as well :)
